# how to view how a neural network remember a certain class of image

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, resnet

I don't really know how to put this into words, I think that is mainly why I can't find much by searching.

In many tutorials, I have have seen people show an output image saying in the network this is how the network sees the specific class. I think this image is generated using the trained weights. I want to get an image like this from a large image classification network like inception or resnet.

If someone can understand what I am asking, please feel free to edit the question or give me some idea about how I can search for this. Of course, how to get this image is the best answer

Comment: Now, I know there are lots of people who want to close this question.. but please, give me some reference before that :)

Comment: Could you perhaps share some examples of the kind of output you’re talking about?

Comment: `weights` are numbers and pixels in image are also numbers. If you create 2D numpy.array with integer numbers `0-255` (in some situations float numbers `0-1`) then you can display this array as image with `cv2.imshow("text", array)`, `imageio.imshow(array)`, `matplotlib.pyplot.imshow(array)` or `PIL.Image.fromarray(array).show()`

Comment: @AlexanderCécile i am looking for one, but i can't seem to remember where i saw it